# Android- how to Convert library project to external jar files

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

i have a requirement like i have to use one app for two other applications. so i want to create a library project as jar file so that i can use that in build path easily with out adding the project. so i have added my main project as a library project  so it has generated jar file in bin folder . so i have copied that jar file and added to libs and added that to my project build path. but still i am getting no class def found exception. please sugest whether this process of generating a jar file is correct or not. if it is not correct please suggest me how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Rightclick on the library project, export -> Jar file.

Select all files, except the AndroidManifest.xml.

Make sure you DON'T select manifest file. Else it will lead to conflict errors.

Now include this JAR file in the build path, and it will work. I did the same.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: still i am getting no class def found exception

Comment: Are you refering an Activity in the library project? If yes, did you put that in the manifest file of the application? If not, what kind of class is it?

Comment: yes i have added all the activities which are in library project i am mentioning in manifest file also. and i am navigating to the activity which is in the library project from my application project

Comment: please see that link i have pasted the log

Comment: Did you add the jar file to the build path?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20160/discussion-between-sravani-and-nithinreddy)

Comment: I am having the same issue, was there ever a resolution reached here?

Answer (score 2):

The Most Important thing , your project doesn't contain any Resources (RES folder) then

1- Right Click on **Project –> Export —> Java –> JarFile**

2-**Select only the src checkbox** ie the (pacakages) in Top-Left Window.
**Don’t Select** anything in Top-Right Window if some thing is selected  remove marks .

3-Select Only **Export generates Class Files and Resources**

4-In **Options** Select only **Compress the contents of the jar file** (it's not important)

To add your External Jar to Your File

1-Right click on project –> Select Properties –> Java Build Path —> libraries –> Add External Jar Files –> Click OK

2-**CLEAN** your Project

Answer (score 1):

You can export your project as a jar.To do this

```
right click your project->export->java->JAR file->Next
```

But if you use resources in the library project then you won't get it from the jar.But it will be available if you use as a library project rather than jar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export a library project to a JAR file
A library cannot be distributed as a binary file (such as a JAR file). This will be added in a future version of the SDK Tools.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following:
  Add reference of .jar file to your client application. Right click project -> properties -> Click 'Java Build Path' -> open Libraries tab -> Click button 'Add External JARs..' and select the .Jar file that you have created -> Go to 'Order and Export' tab and select the Added external Jar and move it to the top.

I hope this will help you.
Mark +1 if it is helpful to you.